# Removing Anonymous DIV from search-block-form

Tags: 7, forms, blocks

I have created a sub theme under [Bootstrap](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap) and am having issues removing the "anonymous" div from inside the form.

Here is the displayed code:

`<section id="block-search-form" class="block block-search clearfix">
    <form class="form-search content-search form-search content-search" action="/" method="post" id="search-block-form" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <div><!-- This guy needs to go -->
            <div class="input-group">
                <input title="" placeholder="Search" class="form-control form-text form-search" type="search" id="edit-search-block-form--2" name="search_block_form" value="" size="5" maxlength="128">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-XXXX">
            <input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="search_block_form">
            <button class="element-invisible element-invisible btn btn-primary form-submit" id="edit-submit" name="op" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</section>`

I have my own versions of `form-element.func.php` and `search-block-form.tpl.php` and I have created my own theme wrapper to customize this as much as possible but I still cannot figure out a way to get rid of that stupid div!

How can I remove this div WITHOUT modifying the Bootstrap theme or the Drupal Core?

Edit: At the very least, I would be ok with adding the class `input-group` onto the div and getting rid of the current `div.input-group`

Comment: Here is already an answer on Stackexchange: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/41794/28126

Comment: I can't believe I didn't find that during my search :-( Thanks for finding me the answer!